# Prove that the set of all finite sets of reals has cardinality $ 2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have tried using some properties of Cardinal Arithmetic but I haven't made any significant process besides the pretty easy result that if $S$ is the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $| \mathbb{R} | \leq |S|$

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Let $A_k$ be the set of sequences $(a_1,...,a_k)$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and use that $A_k$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ and that a countable union of sets with the cardinality of the continuum, still has the cardinality of the continuum.